# How to edit word documents with php?

Tags: php, ms-word, phpword

I have an existing word document in my computer and like to edit this file from my website (using PHP). I was able to find `PHPWORD` but this deals with new documents only. I don't want to code `PHP` for the whole document, instead wish to use it for the stuff that varies.

Does anybody know any way out?

Comment: PHPWord doesn't only deal with new documents.... it provides both Readers and Writers, meaning that it can be used to edit documents

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

PHPWord also features a Reader which can be used to edit existing documents.

Comment: Ok, I got it but now I want to know how to create a section at a particular spot? My document has so many sections, they have titles too. Is there any way I can search for a particular title and create a section underneath it? Other way of doing it is replacing those sections with `$(value)` and then edit the doc but I don't know how many values I am going to receive and `$(values)` might be insufficient or surplus which will look bad on the document. Any ideas?

Comment: @Adarsh did you have any success dealing with find/replace within a document?

Comment: This solution does not work. `$document->setValue('value1', '<strong>Description</strong>');` any suggestion?

Answer (score 5):

@nssmart,

Yes,mark a section on your word document with a variable such as `{value1}` and then, if you have PHPWORD downloaded, you can replace that section using code

```
$PHPWord = new PHPWord();

$document = $PHPWord->loadTemplate(Doc location);

$document->setValue('value1', 'Description');
```

This can be used to fill data in tables also.

Comment: Could someone tell me how to do this in reacent word with the weird menus? I thought I would be able to "Insert -> Field" and then give a field name and value. But I simply can not find it in the new menu, and the one I find I cant find a way to set the field name.

Comment: This solution does not work. `$document->setValue('value1', '<strong>Description</strong>');` any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord
I also did this problem in phpword using the following code

```
 if(!file_exists('file/word.docx')){
  $templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor('demo.docx');
  $templateProcessor->setValue('name', 'Akbarali');
  $templateProcessor->setValue('time','13.02.2021');
  $templateProcessor->setValue('month', 'January');
  $templateProcessor->setValue('state','Uzbekistan');
  $templateProcessor->saveAs('file/word.docx');
}
```

This will change the words in the demo.docx file. The new file is then saved in the word.docx file folder.
you can define variables in the form of $ {name} in the demo word file.
that is, ${name}, ${time}, ${month} and ${state}

Comment: Are these variables? I cannot seem to be able to change the text

Comment: https://uzhackersw-uz.translate.goog/blog/web-dasturlash/phpword-word-fayllarini-taxrirlash.html?_x_tr_sl=uz&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=uz&_x_tr_pto=wapp

Comment: I want to save as PDF

Comment: Then you need to use a library that converts the Word file to PDF

Comment: This solution does not work. `$document->setValue('value1', '<strong>Description</strong>');` any suggestion?