# To edit or modify a docx file using PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to edit/modify a docx file using php only. I have checked online but not able to get appropriate answer. Any help would be highly appreciated. Anyone can help please?

Comment: Maybe you can use this: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

Comment: Or you can try a google search?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975256/how-to-edit-word-documents-with-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to edit word documents with php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975256/how-to-edit-word-documents-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

In our project we are using [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) for that purpose.

Comment: I have tried many ways even PHPWord but still no success yet. Can anyone show me the step by step on how to accomplish this please? I am relatively new to PHP & any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.